# FragmentTransaction working only in portrait mode

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-appcompat

I have a really weird behaviour of my Android code.

The actual question is after the code.

What I want to do is having an application which works only in portait mode on phones and in both portrait and landscape mode on tablet. To do so, I created three bool.xml file in different folders. This one is in the folders values:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">true</bool>
</resources>
```

while in the values-xlarge and values-sw600dp I put

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

The only activity in the project loads, at startup a splash screen by attaching a SplashScreenFragment. Here it is the Activity

```java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)) 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new SplashScreenFragment()).commit();
    }
}
}
```

The fragment itself just loads a layout and starts a TimerTask which changes the fragment. Here it is

```java
public class SplashScreenFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false);

        Timer splashScreenTimer = new Timer();
        splashScreenTimer.schedule(new SplashScreenTimerTask(getActivity()), 2000);

        return rootView;
    }

    private class SplashScreenTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        private FragmentActivity activity;

        public SplashScreenTimerTask(FragmentActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentMain());
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }

}
```

Now, if I start on my phone, the application in portrait mode, everything works flawlessly, while if I start the app with my mobile in landscape mode, then the first fragment gets loaded perfectly, but when the line

```
transaction.commit();
```

gets executed, the app crashes with the following error in the logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17433): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
E/AndroidRuntime(17433): Process: it.assottica.android, PID: 17433
E/AndroidRuntime(17433): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1354)
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1372)
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at it.assottica.android.fragments.SplashScreenFragment$SplashScreenTimerTask.run(SplashScreenFragment.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime(17433):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening and how to solve it? But, above all, why everything works fine if I start the app with the mobile in landscape or portrait mode?

Comment: @the-guy-with-the-hat, thanks for editing, although I don't get why I can't thank somebody in advance. As you're an editor, I have a question for you: now that I have solved my own problem, can I mark my answer as correct or do I break some stackoverflow's policy?

Comment: Yes. You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/), but you must wait 48 hours to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/2846923) answer to _Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?_, specifically where it says "Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should be removed.

That includes...signatures, 'thanks'..."

And yes, you can and should accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem by tracing deeply what methods, among onPause, onStop both of Activity and Fragment were actually executed.

Differently from what I thought, when I started the orientation with the mobile in landscape mode, the Activity and the Fragment went through the following process: onCreateView -> onPause -> onStop -> onDestroy -> onCreateView, that is exactly the same process happening when you start an Activity in an orientation and then change the screen orientation. This caused the Fragment to be started, then destroyed and then restarted, so the timer created at the first start, tried to get the support fragment manager of an activity which actually didn't exist or to perform a transaction after the execution of onSaveInstanceState.

I solved by cancelling the timer in the onDestroy() method of the Fragment.